# Canvas getWidth() and getHeight() in android-10 and android-23

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm writing android code where I draw a custom view on canvas (allocated some portion of the screen)

For this I'm using `canvas.getWidth()` and `canvas.getHeight()`.

In android versions above `ICS`, I'm able to see the view and it's working fine.

But in `gingerbread` and `froyo`, it's not working.

When I tried to debug, I found that `canvas.getWidth()` and `canvas.getHeight()` are giving wrong values (in fact they are returning screen dimensions) in `gingerbread` and `froyo`.

Please help me.

Comment: show us how did you use it in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. Hope this helps someone.
I changed the calls "canvas.getWidth()" and "canvas.getHeight()" to just getWidth() and getHeight().